# Am I allowed to enqueue scripts like this to control what pages they are on?

Tags: plugins

I am working on my first WordPress plugin.  The plugin basically creates a few short codes to achieve a few effects.  In order to only include all of the css and js files on the pages where they are needed I have set my wp_enqueue_* function calls to be called if a short code is activated.  That may not have been a very clear description so here are code snippets related to what I am talking about:

```
add_shortcode( 'slider_space', 'f_slider_space');

function link_page_files(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'cccslider-style', plugins_url("...") );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.easing', plugins_url("..."), array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollcontrol', plugins_url("...") );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cccslider', plugins_url("..."), array('jquery.easing', 'scrollcontrol') );
    }

function f_slider_space($atts, $content = null){
link_page_files();
// ..........
}
```

It seems to be working, but I am wondering if this is not best practice.  What solution is best for controlling which pages the files are included in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would print the stylesheet links into the footer. Works in most browsers, but is invalid HTML. You should hook into the action `wp_head` instead and check the post content for your shortcodes. Use a priority `0` to run earlier than the the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'shortcode_check', 0 );

function shortcode_check() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( empty ( $wp_query ) or empty ( $wp_query->posts ) )
        return;

    foreach ( $wp_query->posts as $post )
    {
        if ( FALSE !== stripos( $post->post_content, '[shortcodename' ) )
            return add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shortcode_enqueue' );
    }
}

function shortcode_enqueue() {
    // enqueue scripts and stylesheets here
}
```